# Is it a good idea to add .pytest_cache to ci runner's cache?

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, pytest, gitlab-ci

As I understand `.pytest_cache` stores a mtime of last check. I curious if addition of it into ci-runner's cache could optimize the time of ci-jobs and maybe reduce unnecessary tasks? I use gitlab ci and shared `cache` section between all jobs for instance, but I think the question is quite general for all ci-processes.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the question, but this is kinda obvious to me - if you spend more time to populate the empty cache than to send the `.pytest_cache` to the runner, then it's a good idea, otherwise not.

Comment: Yes, I have the same thoughts but I'm not sure to to measure those durations correctly